# webgl shadow mapping gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, shadow, glsles

Hey im trying to implement shadow mapping in webgl using this example:
[tutorial](http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/07/using-webgldepthtexture.html)

What im trying to do is

initialize the depth texture and framebuffer. 
draw a scene to that framebuffer with a simple shader, then draw a new scene with a box that has the depthtexture as texture so i can see the depth map using an other shader.

I think i look ok with the colortexture but cant get i to work with the depthtexture its all white.

i put the code on dropbox:
[source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9890746/webglprojekt.zip)
most is in the files
index html
webgl_all js
objects js

have some light shaders im not using at the moment.

Really hope somebody can help me.

greetings from denmark

Comment: Not an actual answer, but this is something that I noted when looking at your code (not yet completely through it): 1: you seem to be resetting the values for the uniform locations every frame, which isn't neccessary, do it once and then let them be. 2: you have initiallised webGL only ith experimental-webGL, which made it unlable to run without changes for me (had to change it to webGL, using firefox 27.0). Further code analysations will probably follow, along with an answer if I find one

Answer (score 0):

This could have several causes:

- For common setups of the near and far planes, normalized depth values will be high enough to appear all white for most of the scene, even though they are not actually identical (remember that a depth texture has an accuracy of at least 16bits, while your screen output has only 8 bits per color channel. So a depth texture may appear all white, even when its values are not all identical.)
- On some setups (e.g. desktop OpenGl), a texture may appear all white, when it is incomplete, that is when texture filtering is set to use mipmaps, but not all mipmap levels have been created. This may be the same with WebGl.
- You may have hit a browser WebGl implementation bug.